# Ruby create an object from a query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, query-string

I am using a new Rails project & an old established Oracle db using adapter: oracle_enhanced. Would like to be able to have dynamic searches against the db depending upon what info/field(s) is available to search against.

I am trying to get from

```
http://www.abc.com/order/show?acct_num=a123&po_num=789z
```

and create an object such as

```
class Order
  attr_reader :customer_name, :acct_num, :order_date, :po_num, :qty.
end
```

I have the paramaters from the **request.query_parameters** hashtable.

Now in case I am going down the wrong path what I want to do is use the query string and be able to find all orders where acct_num_in_model = acct_num_from_query_string and po_num_from_model = po_num_from_query_string etc. If something is empty such as po_number then return all that match the acct_number and if acct_num empty all that match that po. I am expecting the following:

```
abc.com/order/show?acct_num=a123&po_num=789z
```

to return all orders with acct_num=a123 and po_num=789z

abc.com/order/show?acct_num=a123
to return all orders with acct_num = a123

```
abc.com/order/show?po_num=789z
```

to return all orders with po_num = 789z

```
abc.com/order/show?po_num=789z&qty=6
```

to return all orders with po_num = 789z & qty=6

Comment: Could you update your question and indicate how you are accessing your database - is it Rails, Sequel etc?

Comment: Just to save some folks from replying with Rails-based solutions when it may not be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to use rails, I suggest this:

```
QUERY_WHITELIST = ['po_num','qty','acct_num']
Order.find :all, :conditions => params.slice(*QUERY_WHITELIST)
```

or

```
QUERY_WHITELIST = ['po_num','qty','acct_num']
Order.all :conditions => params.slice(*QUERY_WHITELIST)
```

depending on your Rails version.

Comment: when I use this solution I get ArgumentError Unknown key(s): conditons (that is the erros spelling not mine of conditions). I believe that is because if I do params.inspect I get ..."action"=>"show", "controller"=>"order"} included in the list.

So I changed params.slice(*QUERY_WHITELIST) to request.query_string.slice(*QUERY_WHITELIST) because request.query_string contains only the parameters from the querystring but that gives me  TypeError in OrderController#show can't convert String into Integer.

So this is not working for me.

Comment: The slice method "filters" the params, so the result no longer would contain "action" or "controller". query_string however is a string - you don't want to use that (unless you want to fiddle around with parameter parsing und unescaping). I'll try to reproduce. Check back later.

Comment: What database interface do you use? My resolution is for ActiveRecord... Are you sure you spelled "conditions" right in your code? Happens to me sometimes.

Comment: It is active record and you were ABSOLOUTLY CORRECT! I did mispell condition as conditon. WOW thank you so much!! I think it is working exactly correct. I love how I can do order/show?acct_num=xyz or order/show/acct_numb=xyz&po_num_as_int=1234 and it dynamically creates the query based on whats there and even knows if it should be a string or number.
Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: For the database query it doesn't matter if you compare to the string "123" or to the integer 123... Both match. So rails passes strings anyway (from the params hash).